# Cross referencing two csv files in python

Tags: python

so as i'm out of ideas I've turned to geniuses on this site.

What I want to be able to do is to have two separate csv files. One of which has a bunch of store names on it, and the other to have black listed stores.

I'd like to be able to run a python script that reads the 'black listed' sheet, then checks if those specific names are within the other sheet, and if they are, then delete those off the main sheet.

I've tried for about two days straight and cannot for the life of me get it to work. So i'm coming to you guys to help me out.

Thanks so much in advance.

p.s If you can comment the hell out out of the script so I know what's going on it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I deleted the code I originally had but hopefully this will give you an idea of what I was trying to do. (I also realise it's completely incorrect)

```
import csv

with open('Black List.csv', 'r') as bl:
    reader = csv.reader(bl)

    with open('Destinations.csv', 'r') as dest:
        readern = csv.reader(dest)

        for line in reader:
            if line in readern:
                with open('Destinations.csv', 'w'):
                    del(line)
```

Comment: Could you describe you approach?  What do you have so far?  What particular part isn't working?

Comment: welcome to SO, you will not get a code written for you here. read the guidelines.

Comment: Please, tell us what you've done so far

Comment: I basically open up two files and read the lines. I then try an state that if anything within the black list file is in the other file, write to the file and delete them so all that remains is the stores that i need. I've tried a few things from this site but nothing seems to actually work. the sheets remain the same.

Comment: @DamonPercival. [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49088820/edit) and add all the code you have so far.

Comment: Will do, I deleted most of what i had as it didn't work. So will write something up and post it.

Comment: Please give us a small example of what is in both files and the expected output.

Comment: So as an eg. On the black list sheet, there would 'Telford'. What i would then be doing is pasting a bunch of store locations into the next sheet, which wouldn't be filtered. So that's where the black list sheet would come into play, and delete anything that's on the black list sheet off of the other sheet, so i'm then left with the stores that arn't black listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to be aware of is that you can't update the file you are reading. Textfiles (which include .csv files) don't work like that. So you have to read the whole of `Destinations.csv` into memory, and then write it out again, under a new name, but skipping the rows you don't want. (You *can* overwrite your input file, but you will very quickly discover that is a bad idea.)

```
import csv

blacklist_rows = []
with open('Black List.csv', 'r') as bl:
    reader = csv.reader(bl)
    for line in reader:
        blacklist_rows.append(line)

destination_rows = []
with open('Destinations.csv', 'r') as dest:
    readern = csv.reader(dest)
    for line in readern:
        destination_rows.append(line)
```

Now at this point you need to loop through `destination_rows` and drop any that match something in `blacklist_rows`, and write out the rest. I can't suggest what the matching test should look like, because you haven't shown us your input data, so I don't actually know that `blacklist_rows` and `destination_rows` contain.

```
with open('FilteredDestinations.csv', 'w') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    for r in destination_rows:
        if not r:   # trap for blank rows in the input
            continue
        if r *matches something in blacklist_rows*: # you have to code this
            continue
        writer.writerow(r)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works amazingly. The only thing that's a minor issue is, when writing the new file. It has an empty cell in between everything that's been wrote to the sheet. Do you know how i could correct that?

Comment: It's hard to say for sure without seeing your input but it sounds as though `csv.reader` thinks there is a blank row after every row of data. That happens a lot because of the way not all software can agree on how end-of-line is represented. If so, there are 3 ways to fix it. (1) Fix the input. (2) Tell `csv.reader` what the end-of-line looks like (`lineterminator=...`). (3) Just pass over the blank lines. I've edited the code to provide solution (3).

Comment: I messed around with it after it started happening and ending up adding newline= ''  at the end of the new file being wrote and this seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks so much for the help though. Your info has helped greatly now that I know how files properly work.

Comment: If the answer worked for you, please accept it. If setting `newline=''` on output does the trick, that probably indicates there is a trailing newline in your input data. Because without it all the data would be output on one line.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("Destinations.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("Black List.csv")

blacklist = df2["column_name_in_blacklist_file"].tolist()

df3 = df2[~df2['destination_column_name'].isin(blacklist)]

df3.to_csv("results.csv")
print(df3)
```